# searching for the non-friend users in php

Tags: php, mysql, search

I am logged in and my id is: mekha_id

I have 2 tables:
1) registration    id,username,...
2) sed_request   rid,sender_id,reciever_id
i want to do a search.php

searching for value like “mekhaname” in registration(username)..get the registration[id] of “mekhaname”...go to sed_request table and check if there is a row in sed_request that includes mekha_id and registration[id] in the same row....for example:

mekha_id is the reciever_id abd registration[id] is the sender_id....or mekha_id is the sender_id and registration[id] is the reciever_id....if yes....I dont want this user (registration[id]) to appear in my search result in REGISTRATION table,,,,,, I hope you get me.....
this is my code

```
<?php
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM `registration` where username LIKE '%$search%' and id!=$user_id;";
    $result1 = mysql_query($sql) or die('Errant query2:'.$sql);

    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result1)) {
        $data[] = $row;
    }
?>
```

any help please?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it lacks information to diagnose the problem. Consider providing proper DDLs (and/or an sqlfiddle) TOGETHER WITH THE DESIRED RESULT SET.

Comment: Really hard to understand your question also your needs. Could you explain more clearly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to perform a search on "registration" and exclude ID of users which are in sed_request and where reciever_id or sender_id are current user id ?

```
SELECT *
FROM `registration`
WHERE username LIKE '%$search%'
AND id != $user_id
AND id NOT IN (
    SELECT sender_id
    FROM sed_request 
    WHERE reciever_id = $user_id
)
AND id NOT IN (
    SELECT reciever_id
    FROM sed_request 
    WHERE sender_id = $user_id
)
```

Comment: man...i have 2 users !
1)user_id of me
2)user_id of the $search
i want to check in sed_request...where the SAME ROW doesn't have those id's...
the sed_request row: id | sender_id | receiver_id
i don't want user_id of me and user_id of $search to be in the same row...as a receiver or as a sender..both of us..